# Npm run build Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, npm

When I run npm run build in any react project that I code, it creates build folder, but when I click index.html file, the browser shows blank page. Why? How can I fix this? Console shows me no errors.

Comment: Is index.html supposed to be filled with something? If so, what?

Comment: index.html file supposed to show me what I have done in react project. Background color, menu, buttons etc.

Comment: Because you need a server to serve index.html and the static assets including JS and CSS. Choose any server you prefer to work with.